# Android 4.1.x & OpenGL ES 2.0: failed to link shaders

Tags: android, opengl-es

Hello Android / OpenGL gurus,

I've got a problem where my (OpenGL ES 2.0-based) program will fail to link the shaders . The problem only occurs on certain 4.1.x (4.1.1 and sometimes 4.1.2) versions of Android; all versions >= 4.2 (and I've checked some 40 different phone models) are ok; all Android emulators (including the 4.1.1 and 4.1.2) are also ok; 4.0.3 devices like the Kindle Fire also work ok.

This is what the log says:

> DEBUG|11-21 21:24:16.391|18456|18474||v_gal|[tid=18474] gcmERR_BREAK: status=-16(**gcvSTATUS_OUT_OF_RESOURCES**) @ gcLinkShaders(7936)
>   DEBUG|11-21 21:24:16.391|18456|18474||v_gal|[tid=18474] gcmONERROR: status=-16(**gcvSTATUS_OUT_OF_RESOURCES**) @ gcLINKTREE_GenerateStates(12663)
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.391|18456|18474||Distorted|Error compiling program:
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime|FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 7888
>   **WARNING|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||dalvikvm|threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4183ec08)**
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime| at com.threedcell.distorted.edgedrag.EdgeDragRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(EdgeDragRenderer.java:114)
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime| at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime| at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime|java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating program.
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime| at com.threedcell.distorted.Distorted.createAndLinkProgram(Distorted.java:491)
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime| at com.threedcell.distorted.Distorted.init(Distorted.java:89)
>   ERROR|11-21 21:24:16.411|18456|18474||AndroidRuntime|Process: com.threedcell.distorted.edgedrag, PID: 18456

Notice the 'gcvSTATUS_OUT_OF_RESOURCES' - to me it looks like the shader compiler/linker is out of resources and that made some internal dalvik thread crash.

The vertex shader is indeed quite big (3000 lines, ~50 uniforms etc etc).

The question is: is there a way to learn more what exactly is out of resources here? Is it the number of uniforms, the code size, number of local variables or what?

Additionally, as a curiosity - the shader makes ALL 2.3.x phones... hard reboot! Just start my program and watch the phone lock and reboot after a few seconds :) I don't care about that though, I am not going to support anything < 4.x.

Comment: I have exactly the same pb, but my shaders are nit that big (10 uniforms). Did you find a clue ?